# How to video chat with a PowerBook G4

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, powerpc, chat, video-conference

I have a PowerBook G4 (1.33Ghz, 1.5 GB ram) and would like to use it to video chat with my mom, who has newer apple products (FaceTime and the like).

I don’t know if iChat is a viable option or if a different application can bridge the years in hardware and OS to have a family  video chat?

Comment: This might get tricky, not sure a G4 has enough CPU power for any modern video chat solution. You could try a web-based approach (i.e. Jiitsi Meet), assuming you can get a modern browser to run on it.

Comment: Is iChat completely unusable in nowdays?

Comment: I don‘t have an old Mac to try, but it for sure requires some central infrastructure to run. Not sure this is still available, also not sure iChat and Messages/Facetime can interoperate.

Comment: I'd agree that the G4 CPU does not have enough power to cope with video decompression in real time. FaceTime requires a newer OS than can run on PPC, too.  18 years is a long time in technology.

Comment: I'm pretty sure people did video chat on PPC machines back in the day? It should have the CPU power in theory—just don't go expecting 1080p video, 360p is probably more realistic (and for the purpose of video chat should be acceptable.)

Comment: I think (!) iChat just needs an XMPP server—but unless you're planning to self-host I don't know of a good one! I could use iChat (on Intel) with Google Talk up until a few months ago once I enabled Less Secure Apps in my Google Account, although only for text, I never tried video, and it's also gone now.

Comment: Yep, iChat. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/resurrecting-ichat-audio-video-conferencing.2376855/

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up an Apple Silicon device with a camera. Any used recent OS supporting iPod touch is fine or iPad or iPhone or Mac.
2. Show off your awesome G4 for vintage workloads in the video chat.

If you must use the PPC, I’d add this webcam for offloading all the graphics work. Some assembly (especially software stack) required.

- https://www.adafruit.com/product/3414